# I am trying to tweet a picture that shows up in the image picker. but the app crashes in between. how can i fix this?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(IBAction)twitterPost:(id)sender
    {
            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController
                                                   composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
            SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock =
            ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
                if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                }
              else{
                    NSLog(@"Done");
                }
                [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            };
            controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
            //Adding the Text to the facebook post value from iOS
            [controller setInitialText:@"Calendar Helper is the Best App EVER!!"];
            [controller addImage:ivPickedImage];
            //Adding the URL to the facebook post value from iOS
            [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com"]];
            //Adding the Text to the facebook post value from iOS
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        - (IBAction)btnGalleryClicked:(id)sender
        {
            ipc= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            ipc.delegate = self;
            ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
                [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
            else
            {
                popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:ipc];
                [popover presentPopoverFromRect:btnGallery.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
            }
        }

        - (IBAction)btnCameraClicked:(id)sender
        {
            ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            ipc.delegate = self;
            if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
            {
                ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:NULL];
            }
            else
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Camera Available." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                alert = nil;
            }
        }

        #pragma mark - ImagePickerController Delegate

        -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
        {
            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            } else {
                [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            }
            ivPickedImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        }
```

Comment: what is the error and show your crash report

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Debug the program, and find in which statement it is crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and let me know what happen...

```
- (IBAction)takeNewPhotoButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender 
{  
    isfromGallery = FALSE;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])     
    {
                  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];         
          picker.delegate = self;
          picker.allowsEditing = YES;
          picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;         
          picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;      
          if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)              
          [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];          
     else         
     {              
           popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:picker];
          [popover presentPopoverFromRect:btnGallery.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];          
       }              
 }     
else     
{         
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Camera is not available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];         
    [alert show];     
   } 
}   

- (IBAction)uploadFromFileButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender 
{     
    isfromGallery = TRUE;     
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];    
    picker.delegate = self;     
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;       
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }    

 UIImage *pickedImg;
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {     
        pickedImg =  info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];      
         // Your remaining code               
         [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{         
      // If you want to do something here     
     }]; 
}   

- (IBAction)btnTwitterClicked:(id)sender 
{     
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];  
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"your text";  
    [tweetSheet addImage:pickedImg];      // pickedImg that is capture by camera or select from gallery
    [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.yoururl.com"]];     
    [tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)      
{    
      NSString *msg = @“”;          
      switch (result)          
      {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:                  
              msg = @Your message has been cancelled;                  
               break;

        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:                  
                msg = Message successfully sent.";               
                break;                                

        default:                 
                 break;         
     }   
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];          
     [alert show];      
}];    
 [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{        
     // If you want to do something here     
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: I think a little bit of formatting should be welcomed.

Comment: Yeah sure.... sorry about formatting because it is posted by app and I do not know how to format text there. :(

Comment: Had to tweak a few things but it worked :) Thank You! :)